# Embed web inspector console in a page

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector

Is there any way to embed "console" tab from chrome web inspector in a page?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not know of a way to do this in a normal web page in any browser but you could make an [Electron app](http://electron.atom.io/) and perhaps show the inspector whenever you want for the user.

If you are looking to embed a JS console emulator on your site, perhaps to show off raw JavaScript, you can use [YourJS Console](https://yourjs.com/console/).  It also gives you the ability to initialize the console with custom code or a GitHub Gist.